# Grid is displaying stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to using grid in CSS and for some reason i cant get it to work in a page i am making to display a batch of photos.

For some reason all the images are displaying on top of each other on the right hand side of the page (i can tell lthis from inspecting the results in the browsers developers tools).

Any idea what im doing wrong. Below is my CSS and markup:

```
#index-gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p"
    "gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2"
    "img1 img2 img3 img4"
     "img5 img6 img7 img8"
     "img9 img10";
}

#index-gallery .gallery-img {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* Images */
#index-gallery p{
    grid-area: gallery-p;
  
}

#index-gallery h2{
    grid-area: gallery-h2;
 
}

#index-gallery .img1{
        grid-area: img1;
        background-image: url("../img/thumbs/img1.jpg");
}

#index-gallery .img2{
    grid-area: img2;
    background-image: url("../img/thumbs/img2.jpg");
}

#index-gallery .img3{
    grid-area: img3;
    background-image: url("../img/thumbs/img3.jpg");
}

/*  etc on to img10 */
```

And my markup:

```
<section id="index-gallery" class="wrapper-gallery">
    <p>Peter Wilson</p>
    <h2>My Photo Gallery</h2>

    <div class="gallery-img img1">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img2">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img3">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img4">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img5">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img6">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img7">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img8">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img9">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-img img10">
        <div><a href="#">This is a title</a></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: A proper [mcve] would be useful but I'd start by removing `width:100%`

Comment: Removing the width did not change anything. As i understood it that was there to make the images stretch the full width of their grid container.
I will try and add the mre later on as i am not in a position to do so now

Comment: But you aren't using inline images you're using background images. A proper [mcve] is required to diagnose

Comment: yes i get that, i just could get back to my PC to provide it.
For the MRE do i just need to change the CSS and markup in my example so that it can be run properly?

Comment: You have invalid `grid-template-areas` values. Read the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) (see demos) and use browser inspector such as Firefox to see the warning of yours.

Comment: I did use the inpector in firefox and the console has no errors in it. When i inspect the element in question it reports back the correct grid-area: name and the background image is shown correctly.
Can you elaborate on how my grid-template-areas are invalid? Sorry if thats a silly question but i am very new to grid

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out myeself! The error was down to the last line of my grid-template-areas: setting. It didnt like that I only had 2 columns on the last row when I specified 4 columns above.

I changed it from :

```
grid-template-areas: "gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p"
                         "gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2"
                         "img1 img2 img3 img4"
                         "img5 img6 img7 img8"
                         "img9 img10";
```

To this and it worked:

```
grid-template-areas: "gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p"
                         "gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2"
                         "img1 img2 img3 img4"
                         "img5 img6 img7 img8"
                         "img9 img10 img7 img8";
```